# Production ready STS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, forms-authentication, single-sign-on, adfs

Support for various data sources to use with ADFS 2.0 is limited to Active Directory only. I am in need for a production ready STS to authenticate my users against a forms Authentication inside a portal to access various applications ( Single Sign On). After playing around with ADFS 2.0 came to know that it works against Active Directory only. So my users are inside a SQL table and i want the Portal to issue claims to residing applications after the user provides a username and password. Does anyone have any clues as, how to achieve this using ADFS or some other software from microsoft

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [IdentityServer](http://thinktecture.github.com/).

It authenticates against SQL Server and federates nicely with ADFS.

Comment: StarterSTS and IdentityServer seem to be only choice out there, hmm may be .NET needs a stronger community or better thinkers. Thanks for the same

Comment: StarterSTS is actually the predecessor to IdentityServer.

Answer (score 1):

The mentioned IdentityServer is a good choice. But consider writing your own STS. This is easy and gives you full control over various scenarios (reclaiming lost or expired passwords, single sign out, etc.)

Comment: Being is developer is Great, i love writing code and will see to creating a custom STS Thanks

Comment: I wrote like dozen of STSes, at least four or five are used in production and serve as sso gateways for dozen thousands of users. It is sometimes handy to have an adfs replacement but of course adfs is also a solid piece of software.